# Exception in jobWasExecuted of Quartz listener leaves job as running when actually it finished

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a webapp with a Quartz scheduler. In a page of my app I'm showing the jobs that are currently executing. Today a job failed and, because of some awfull Hibernate problem we got an exception inside the jobWasExecuted method of my job listener.
As I found nothing on Internet or Quartz docs, I went to make some tests and I found that if an Exception occurs inside such listener method (jobWasExecuted) Quartz keeps telling you that the job is currently executing, despite it actually finished.

Has anyone seen or heard of something similar? Any suggested solution or should I directly wrap all this method content inside a giant try-catch to prevent this missbehavior?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to create the smallest possible testcase and show it here.

Comment: It's really simple, if you have a scheduler, just add it a listener and throw a RuntimeException in its jobWasExecuted. Afterwards, as the scheduler for its getCurrentlyExecutingJobs and you'll see it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this locally (using Quartz 2).

Wrapping the jobWasExecuted method statements in a try catch seems to work (the job is no longer recognized as executing afterwards in case of an Exception).

Execution continues in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell#run and executes

```
complete(true);
```

If you feel this is a bug, you might want to file a report on https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/issues.